# Is there any way to customise the location of where replays are autosaved?

Tags: starcraft-2

Since patch 1.2 you've been able to permanently retain replays by default. My question is: do I have any control of where they're saved or am I forced to use SC2Gears for this purpose?

The reason I want to do this is to separate my replays from those I've downloaded and added to the Multiplayer folder - while retaining the ability to launch them in-game. The need for this separation arises from SC2Gears apparent inability to exclude subfolders from replay sources or to save filter searches.

Answer (score 3):

The new patch allows you to put replays in sub folders, can't you place the downloaded ones in one?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can tell SC2Gears will always import subfolders, meaning there's no practical separation at all. (Folders made with Explorer have always worked.)

Answer (score 2):

Create a symlink, for Vista & Windows 7.

1. Move All replays to where you want them to be saved.
2. Delete "%HOMEPATH%\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\YOURACCOUNT\X-XX-X-XXXXXXX\Replays\Multiplayer"
3. mklink /D "%HOMEPATH%\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\YOURACCOUNT\X-XX-X-XXXXXXX\Replays\Multiplayer" "C:\where-you-want-replays-saved"

Comment: My fault completely, but I don't believe this helps me. I've added the reason I want to do this to the question. I was hoping there'd be a way to specify a subfolder of Multiplayer in which replays would be saved. I suppose one solution would be to use the Challenge folder to store third party replays.

Comment: you can create a folder "downloaded" inside your replays folder and save your downloaded ones there.